# How Outer Transaction query should not effect when Inner Transaction fails

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where my Inner Transaction is failing by a condition  not by syntax error so outer transaction should not effect.

Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your question is ? Maybe by giving an example ?

Comment: Nested transactions, in SQL Server, are bit of a Myth, Gaurav; they certainly don't work the way many believe they do. A couple of articles on the subject: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of INNER or OUTER transaction does not exists...

Just have a look at the definition of what is a transaction :
[en.wikipedia.org-wiki/Database_transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)
*"A database transaction, by definition, must be atomic"*

So, can we have subatomic process in an atomic process ? Of course not !

I must say that the concept of transaction is better understood when you think at the session level... ***A session can be in an explicit transaction state or not***.

Any subtransaction is only an artefact needed because you can call a procedure which has its own transaction, that call another procedure that have also its own transaction... The accumulation of BEGIN TRANSACTION ha no effect on the transaction state, this only increments the @@TRANCOUT counter.

The frontier of a transactional state are

- BEGIN TRANSACTION as the entry point
- COMMIT or ROLLBACK at the exit point

When the session is not in the transactional state, @@TRANCOUT is valued to 0.

WHen BEGIN TRANSACTION is executed the @@TRANCOUT is incremented to one

WHEN COMMIT is executed the @@TRANCOUT is decremented to one:

- if the value decrease to 0, the COMMIT will effectively do a COMMIT
- if the value is > 0, nothing happen

When a ROLLBACK is executed, the @@TRANCOUT is immediately valued to 0 and the ROLLBACK is executed

That is why this nested concept of transaction, in this case (MS SQL Server) is called *asymetric model*...

You should have into your code either a test for @@TRANCOUNT or a TRY/CATCH and a test with the XACT_STATE() function to proper code the traitement